# FFMPEG not working from Python subprocess.Popen but works from command line

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run a `FFMPEG` script from within `python 3.5.2`. the `FFMPEG` command runs fine from the command line but fails within the python script.

The function I use to execute the `FFMPEG` command is

```
def ffmpeg(args):
    err = None
    command = [
        ffmpegcmd, '-y',
        '-loglevel', loglevel
    ] + args
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(command)
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(" ".join(command))
    ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    while err == None:
        out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()
        time.sleep(1)
    if err and loglevel=='fatal':
        print(" ".join(command))
        raise Exception(err)
    print(err)
```

The value for args is:

```
['-i', '/var/www/temp/film.mp4', '-vf', 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black', '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4']
```

such that the resultant command being passed to `subprocess.Popen` is:

```
['ffmpeg', '-y', '-loglevel', 'verbose', '-i', '/var/www/temp/film.mp4', '-vf', 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black', '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4']
```

The value of loglevel is `verbose` only for troubleshooting but is intended to run as `fatal`. There are also some `print` commands only in place for troubleshooting.

The reason for wanting to increase the resolution is so that it can be combined later with higher resolution videos.

The result when running from within `python` is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x7f741a37a560] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/temp/film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:06:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 451 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 640x358 (640x368), 313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x7f741a3bc700] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f741a5315e0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f741a54e000] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f741a54f6a0] w:640 h:358 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f741a54e000] w:640 h:358 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1074 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x7f741a54eac0] w:1920 h:1074 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:2 color:0x000000FF
[libx264 @ 0x7f741a5509e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f741a5509e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f741a5509e0] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
```

This results in a file with no content.

When I run the command from the command line I need to add single quotes around the `-vf` video filters `scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black` so the whole command becomes:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -i /var/www/temp/film.mp4 -vf 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black' /var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4
```

Running this command gives the required result.

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x7f3a55c17560] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/temp/film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:06:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 451 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 640x358 (640x368), 313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x7f3a55c59700] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f3a55dce5e0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f3a55deb000] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f3a55dec6a0] w:640 h:358 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f3a55deb000] w:640 h:358 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1074 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x7f3a55debac0] w:1920 h:1074 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:2 color:0x000000FF
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=   46 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.62 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   59 fps= 47 q=29.0 size=     116kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 464.8kbits/
frame=   74 fps= 41 q=29.0 size=     223kB time=00:00:02.56 bitrate= 714.8kbits/
frame=   87 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=     344kB time=00:00:02.98 bitrate= 942.4kbits/
frame=   98 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=     427kB time=00:00:03.34 bitrate=1043.4kbits/
    blah
    blah
    blah
frame=11347 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97550kB time=00:06:18.32 bitrate=2112.3kbits/
frame=11363 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97713kB time=00:06:18.85 bitrate=2112.8kbits/
frame=11380 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97795kB time=00:06:19.41 bitrate=2111.5kbits/
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=11392 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=   98519kB time=00:06:19.77 bitrate=2125.1kbits/s speed=0.69x    
video:92124kB audio:5986kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.416313%
Input file #0 (/var/www/temp/film.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 11392 packets read (14892948 bytes); 11392 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 17803 packets read (6112540 bytes); 17802 frames decoded (18229248 samples); 
  Total: 29195 packets (21005488 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 11392 frames encoded; 11392 packets muxed (94334785 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 17802 frames encoded (18229248 samples); 17803 packets muxed (6129981 bytes); 
  Total: 29195 packets (100464766 bytes) muxed
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] frame I:74    Avg QP:19.08  size: 51540
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] frame P:3506  Avg QP:21.34  size: 19348
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] frame B:7812  Avg QP:24.07  size:  2904
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] consecutive B-frames:  1.3% 20.2%  4.6% 73.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] mb I  I16..4: 19.7% 73.6%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] mb P  I16..4:  3.2%  6.4%  0.1%  P16..4: 52.5%  7.6%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:27.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 23.2%  0.4%  0.0%  direct: 0.5%  skip:75.5%  L0:51.8% L1:46.6% BI: 1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] 8x8 transform intra:66.4% inter:94.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.6% 53.4% 7.3% inter: 5.3% 14.2% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 27%  5% 46%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 19% 20%  4%  7%  7%  7%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 28% 11%  3%  9%  7%  6%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 21% 20% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.5% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] ref P L0: 63.4%  8.9% 21.4%  6.3%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] ref B L0: 89.3%  9.1%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f3a55ded9e0] kb/s:1987.38
[aac @ 0x7f3a55deee80] Qavg: 1160.814
```

and the resulting video is fine.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Stu

Edit

It was suggested that I use a new function to do much the same thing. So I added the following function and used it for the command that I'm having trouble with:

```
def ffmpegPro(args):
    err = None
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        if(" " in arg or "(" in arg or "[" in arg):
            args[i] = "\"" + arg + "\""
    command = [
        ffmpegcmd, '-y',
        '-loglevel', loglevel
    ] + args
    commandStr = " ".join(command)
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(command)
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(commandStr)
    ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(commandStr, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
    while err == None:
        out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()
        time.sleep(1)
    if ffmpeg.returncode == 0 and all([os.path.exists(f) for f in (videoStorage['data_small'], videoStorage['data_big'])]):
        print("Job done.")
    else:
        print("ERROR")
        print(err)
```

The resulting command can now be used in `python` or at the command line without needing to be changed at all. The command is:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -i /var/www/temp/film.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black" /var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4
```

The result when executed in `python` is

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x7fb75053d560] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/temp/film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:06:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 451 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 640x358 (640x368), 313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x7fb75057f700] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7fb7506f45e0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7fb750711000] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7fb7507126a0] w:640 h:358 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7fb750711000] w:640 h:358 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1074 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x7fb750711ac0] w:1920 h:1074 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:2 color:0x000000FF
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7507139e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7507139e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7507139e0] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
Killed
```

Note the `Killed` at the end. Is this significant and why is it only happening when executed in the script?

Here is the output from the command line which results in a successful video file.

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x7fb52cfb3560] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/temp/film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:06:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 451 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 640x358 (640x368), 313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x7fb52cff5700] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7fb52d16a5e0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7fb52d187000] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7fb52d1886a0] w:640 h:358 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7fb52d187000] w:640 h:358 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1074 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x7fb52d187ac0] w:1920 h:1074 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:2 color:0x000000FF
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   59 fps= 41 q=29.0 size=     116kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 464.8kbits/
frame=   71 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=     201kB time=00:00:02.45 bitrate= 671.3kbits/
frame=   80 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=     276kB time=00:00:02.75 bitrate= 822.0kbits/
    Blah
    Blah
    Blah
frame=11337 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97503kB time=00:06:17.98 bitrate=2113.2kbits/
frame=11351 fps= 21 q=26.0 size=   97572kB time=00:06:18.45 bitrate=2112.1kbits/
frame=11371 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97745kB time=00:06:19.11 bitrate=2112.1kbits/
frame=11390 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97852kB time=00:06:19.73 bitrate=2111.0kbits/
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=11392 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=   98519kB time=00:06:19.77 bitrate=2125.1kbits/s speed=0.688x    
video:92124kB audio:5986kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.416313%
Input file #0 (/var/www/temp/film.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 11392 packets read (14892948 bytes); 11392 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 17803 packets read (6112540 bytes); 17802 frames decoded (18229248 samples); 
  Total: 29195 packets (21005488 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 11392 frames encoded; 11392 packets muxed (94334785 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 17802 frames encoded (18229248 samples); 17803 packets muxed (6129981 bytes); 
  Total: 29195 packets (100464766 bytes) muxed
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] frame I:74    Avg QP:19.08  size: 51540
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] frame P:3506  Avg QP:21.34  size: 19348
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] frame B:7812  Avg QP:24.07  size:  2904
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] consecutive B-frames:  1.3% 20.2%  4.6% 73.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] mb I  I16..4: 19.7% 73.6%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] mb P  I16..4:  3.2%  6.4%  0.1%  P16..4: 52.5%  7.6%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:27.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 23.2%  0.4%  0.0%  direct: 0.5%  skip:75.5%  L0:51.8% L1:46.6% BI: 1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] 8x8 transform intra:66.4% inter:94.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.6% 53.4% 7.3% inter: 5.3% 14.2% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 27%  5% 46%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 19% 20%  4%  7%  7%  7%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 28% 11%  3%  9%  7%  6%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 21% 20% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.5% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] ref P L0: 63.4%  8.9% 21.4%  6.3%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] ref B L0: 89.3%  9.1%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb52d1899e0] kb/s:1987.38
[aac @ 0x7fb52d18ae80] Qavg: 1160.814
```

Any more ideas why this is being handled differently in `python` as opposed to the command line?

I'm believe this is a version issue and that is why the below answer did not work for me, things were fine before I upgraded but since then a lot of things have been playing up. I upgraded both `ffmpeg` and `python` versions and don't really want to go back if it can be avoided.

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: Wild guess: Put the filter description in additional single quotes in Python, too (by packing it in double quotes): `['ffmpeg', ..., "'scale=...color=black'", ...]`

Comment: @MichaelButscher this introduces a new error: `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f4500b19280] No such filter: 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black'
Error reinitializing filters!`. This is because it sees the single quotes as part of the argument rather than just wrapping it all up. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120202/ffmpeg-command-working-from-command-line-but-not-from-python-subprocess-popen) had me first change my code from using these single quotes and fixed a previous problem.

Comment: `out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()` perhaps ffmpeg communicates "back to you" via stderr so it is exiting too soon...

Comment: @rogerdpack so I use `while err == None:` and `out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()`, to try and avoid exiting before anything is finished, do you think I'm doing this wrong? Is there another way? What would you suggest?

Comment: I added a `print(ffmpeg.returncode)` and the result is `137` when this command fails. I've extended the use of the new function to other commands that I run and they work fine and return a code of `0` as expected. Any ideas what this `137` means and why I'm getting it?

Comment: I've posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426810/ffmpeg-process-killed-and-raises-returncode-137-when-executed-through-python3-su) which I think more clearly explains the problem of the returncode. The answer to 1 would also answer the other.

Comment: Exit code 137 - Out of memory. That is when the stdout buffer (4K) is overfilled with the info from ffmpeg. Try using the `ffmpeg -v quiet` option to suppress output.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing ffmpeg through subprocess like this:

1.) ffmpeg command as string instead of list.
2.) Double quotes for `-vf` options.
3.) `shell=True`.
4.) `-y` to force ffmpeg to overwrite the new file.
5.) ffmpeg version 3.4 on Python 2.7/Python3.6.

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -threads %s -i %s " % (_threads, _videoFile['path'])
for fmt in ('640:360', '1024:576'):
    cmd += ' ... alot of string concentration here ...' 

print "ffmpeg command is:"
print cmd
print ""

cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = cmd.communicate()
if cmd.returncode == 0 and all([os.path.exists(f) for f in (videoStorage['data_small'], videoStorage['data_big'])]):
    print "Job done."
else:
    print "ERROR"
    print out
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg command is:
ffmpeg -threads 2 -i /home/f3k/mini.elapsed.mov    -to 0:00:41   -vf "boxblur=enable='between(t,5.646,23.353)'"  -s 640:360 -sn -codec:a copy -q:v 1 -threads 2 -y /tmp/result.small.mp4    -to 0:00:41   -vf "boxblur=enable='between(t,5.646,23.353)'"  -s 1024:576 -sn -codec:a copy -q:v 1 -threads 2 -y /tmp/result.big.mp4 

Job done.
```

Comment: This still results in a different outcome between running from the command line and within the script. I'll edit the question to add what I tried and the output.

Comment: I've included the information about this idea and the result at the end of the question. I think it has something to do with the version. I do like your code, it is very tidy but unfortunately it still results in the same outcome for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Investigate why the process gets killed :)

Comment: Regarding the subprocess, i can think of 2 things: Remove the while loop arround communicate(), dont sleep and try write less to stdout or pipe into a file. Elsewise i have no idea, except looking os/system level (free CPUs, memory, disk space, ...) - but that doesnt make much sense to me, when the command works fine from shell.

Comment: I've removed the while loop but still no result. As for the stdout it fails immediately so don't think its something to do with resources.

Comment: I've posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426810/ffmpeg-process-killed-and-raises-returncode-137-when-executed-through-python3-su) which I think more clearly explains the problem of the returncode. The answer to 1 would also answer the other.