# FFMPEG process Killed and raises returncode 137 when executed through python3 subprocess.Popen but runs fine from the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess, popen

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but I have another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414122/ffmpeg-not-working-from-python-subprocess-popen-but-works-from-command-line/47417227) which I don't think was asked very well (or more to the point I realised the actual problem and have a simpler way of asking for help). If you can answer this question you'll have the answer to the other.

I'm using `python 3.5.2` and `ffmpeg 3.3.4-2` and have this function to run my `ffmpeg` commands:

```
def ffmpegPro(args):
    err = None
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        if(" " in arg or "(" in arg or "[" in arg):
            args[i] = "\"" + arg + "\""
    command = [
        ffmpegcmd, '-y',
        '-loglevel', loglevel
    ] + args
    commandStr = " ".join(command)
    ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(commandStr, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
    out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()
    if ffmpeg.returncode != 0:
        print(commandStr + "\n" + "ERROR CODE: " + str(ffmpeg.returncode))
        raise Exception(err)
```

When I pass the following `args` the `returncode` is `137` and the process is `Killed`. This only occurs when executed in `python`, when I run the same command at the `command line` it executes as expected.

```
['-i', '/var/www/temp/film.mp4', '-vf', 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black', '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4']
```

The resulting command is:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -i /var/www/temp/film.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:x=(1920-iw)/2:y=(1080-ih)/2:color=black" /var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4
```

When executed through `python`:

```
ERROR CODE: 137
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getInsta2.py", line 740, in <module>
    populate(media_feed, last, saved)
  File "getInsta2.py", line 679, in populate
    videoPost(media, hasVids, thisSaved)
  File "getInsta2.py", line 639, in videoPost
    processVideo(film, final, noMusic, audios, lengths)
  File "getInsta2.py", line 358, in processVideo
    ffmpegPro(args)
  File "getInsta2.py", line 170, in ffmpegPro
    raise Exception(err)
Exception: ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x7fa3db55a560] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/temp/film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:06:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 451 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 640x358 (640x368), 313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x7fa3db59c700] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7fa3db7115e0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7fa3db72e000] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7fa3db72f6a0] w:640 h:358 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7fa3db72e000] w:640 h:358 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1074 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x7fa3db72eac0] w:1920 h:1074 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:2 color:0x000000FF
[libx264 @ 0x7fa3db7309e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa3db7309e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fa3db7309e0] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
Killed
```

Note the `Killed` at the end. This occurs just before any processing begins.

BUT when run from the `command line` (cutting and pasting the command as outputted by the code) we get:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x7f68c918f560] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/temp/film.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:06:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 451 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 640x358 (640x368), 313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x7f68c91d1700] Reinit context to 640x368, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0x7f68c93465e0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f68c9363000] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7f68c93646a0] w:640 h:358 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7f68c9363000] w:640 h:358 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1074 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x7f68c9363ac0] w:1920 h:1074 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:2 color:0x000000FF
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=   46 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.62 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   59 fps= 46 q=29.0 size=     116kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 464.8kbits/
frame=   72 fps= 40 q=29.0 size=     203kB time=00:00:02.49 bitrate= 667.2kbits/
frame=   84 fps= 36 q=29.0 size=     308kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate= 875.9kbits/
    Blah
    Blah
    Blah
frame=11351 fps= 21 q=26.0 size=   97572kB time=00:06:18.45 bitrate=2112.1kbits/
frame=11367 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=   97732kB time=00:06:18.98 bitrate=2112.5kbits/
frame=11384 fps= 22 q=29.0 size=   97809kB time=00:06:19.56 bitrate=2111.0kbits/
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=11392 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=   98519kB time=00:06:19.77 bitrate=2125.1kbits/s speed=0.715x    
video:92124kB audio:5986kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.416313%
Input file #0 (/var/www/temp/film.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 11392 packets read (14892948 bytes); 11392 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 17803 packets read (6112540 bytes); 17802 frames decoded (18229248 samples); 
  Total: 29195 packets (21005488 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/var/www/temp/videoHD.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 11392 frames encoded; 11392 packets muxed (94334785 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 17802 frames encoded (18229248 samples); 17803 packets muxed (6129981 bytes); 
  Total: 29195 packets (100464766 bytes) muxed
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] frame I:74    Avg QP:19.08  size: 51540
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] frame P:3506  Avg QP:21.34  size: 19348
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] frame B:7812  Avg QP:24.07  size:  2904
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] consecutive B-frames:  1.3% 20.2%  4.6% 73.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] mb I  I16..4: 19.7% 73.6%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] mb P  I16..4:  3.2%  6.4%  0.1%  P16..4: 52.5%  7.6%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:27.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 23.2%  0.4%  0.0%  direct: 0.5%  skip:75.5%  L0:51.8% L1:46.6% BI: 1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] 8x8 transform intra:66.4% inter:94.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.6% 53.4% 7.3% inter: 5.3% 14.2% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 27%  5% 46%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 19% 20%  4%  7%  7%  7%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 28% 11%  3%  9%  7%  6%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 21% 20% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.5% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] ref P L0: 63.4%  8.9% 21.4%  6.3%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] ref B L0: 89.3%  9.1%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f68c93659e0] kb/s:1987.38
[aac @ 0x7f68c9366e80] Qavg: 1160.814
```

and the output video is fine.

Why would this process be killed by python?

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce this. Everything works fine as expected on my machine. Maybe sth wrong with your system, like oom?

Comment: @halfelf, I presume its some kind of setting, maybe something to do with threads but I don't know enough about them to understand it properly. What versions of `ffmpeg` and `python` are you running? Good news that you have it working.

Comment: @halfelf, I have created a cut down version of my code with just the function and passing the args and yes, it works fine. In the full code there is a ffmpeg command run just beforehand which creates the 6 minute/21mb video, what could be happening here that would cause the next process to be killed? Is there something that needs to be cleared? I tried to pause the code with `time.sleep(100)` just before running the killer line but didn't fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I also tried changing `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and setting them to `None` but still getting the same result.

Comment: I've tested on a mac 10.13 with py 3.6.0, ffmpeg 3.4,  and a Ubuntu 16.04.2, with py 3.6.1, ffmpeg 3.3.1, both fine.

Comment: I've been able to work around this by writing to a text file when complete and then having another script carry on when it see's that the text file exists. I still don't know what can cause this 137 code and why the subprocess is being killed.