# ffmpeg runs in terminal but returns error in subprocess.run

Tags: python, ubuntu, ffmpeg, subprocess

I want to run this command in python:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i "/home/exl/—1—ARCHIVE—1—/video/music videos/author --- a2 - name (text).webm" -vf scale=150:-2 -vframes 1 -c:v libwebp -compression_level 6 -quality 100 /home/exl/—1—ARCHIVE—1—/—3—previews—3—/734a8a0bac3a83e0f6c69416a26ec5cd211a6d742f3df63bb72bdbe6431b57c30677bc11551ba4aaaecac15ed2c48de51340a09020b7e9d9479e1e81ff766191.webp
```

In terminal it works fine, but in subprocess returns error. Python code:

```
finished_process = subprocess.run(
                    [
                        '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
                        '-ss', f'00:00:{seconds_shift}',
                        '-i', original_path,
                        '-vf', 'scale=150:-2',
                        '-vframes', '1',
                        '-c:v', 'libwebp',
                        '-compression_level', '6',
                        '-quality', '100',
                        preview_path
                    ],
                    #stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                    #stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                    check=False,
                    capture_output=True
                )
```

`finished_process.stderr.decode()`:

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --disable-everything --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-vulkan --enable-zlib --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libxcb --enable-vdpau --enable-vaapi --enable-encoder='ac3,alac,flac,libfdk_aac,g723_1,mp2,libmp3lame,libopus,libspeex,pcm_alaw,pcm_mulaw,pcm_f32le,pcm_s16be,pcm_s24be,pcm_s16le,pcm_s24le,pcm_s32le,pcm_u8,tta,libvorbis,wavpack,' --enable-encoder='ass,ffv1,libaom_av1,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,mjpeg_vaapi,rawvideo,theora,vp8_vaapi,libopenh264' --enable-decoder='adpcm_g722,alac,flac,g723_1,g729,libfdk_aac,libopus,libspeex,mp2,mp3,m4a,pcm_alaw,pcm_mulaw,pcm_f16le,pcm_f24le,pcm_f32be,pcm_f32le,pcm_f64be,pcm_f64le,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16be_planar,pcm_s24be,pcm_s16le,pcm_s16le_planar,pcm_s24le,pcm_s24le_planar,pcm_s32le,pcm_s32le_planar,pcm_s64be,pcm_s64le,pcm_s8,pcm_s8_planar,pcm_u8,pcm_u24be,pcm_u24le,pcm_u32be,pcm_u32le,tta,vorbis,wavpack,' --enable-decoder='ass,ffv1,mjpeg,mjpegb,libaom_av1,libdav1d,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,rawvideo,theora,vp8,vp9,libopenh264' --enable-encoder='bmp,gif,jpegls,png,tiff,webp,' --enable-decoder='bmp,gif,jpegls,png,tiff,webp,' --enable-hwaccel='vp8_vaapi,mjpeg_vaapi,' --enable-parser='aac,ac3,flac,mjpeg,mpegaudio,mpeg4video,opus,vp3,vp8,vp9,vorbis,' --enable-muxer='ac3,ass,flac,g722,gif,matroska,mp3,mpegvideo,rtp,ogg,opus,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16le,wav,webm,' --enable-demuxer='aac,ac3,ass,flac,g722,gif,image_jpeg_pipe,image_png_pipe,image_webp_pipe,matroska,mjpeg,mov,mp3,mpegvideo,ogg,pcm_mulaw,pcm_alaw,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16le,rtp,wav,' --enable-filter='crop,scale,overlay,amix,amerge,aresample,format,aformat,fps,transpose,pad,' --enable-indev='v4l2,xcbgrab,' --enable-protocol='crypto,file,pipe,rtp,srtp,rtsp,tcp,udp,unix,' --arch=x86_64 --enable-libopenh264
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/home/exl/—1—ARCHIVE—1—/video/music videos/author --- a2 - name (text).webm':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:03:24.98, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 915 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1036, SAR 1:1 DAR 480:259, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:24.960000000
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:24.981000000
[NULL @ 0x55dd82de7d00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '/home/exl/—1—ARCHIVE—1—/—3—previews—3—/734a8a0bac3a83e0f6c69416a26ec5cd211a6d742f3df63bb72bdbe6431b57c30677bc11551ba4aaaecac15ed2c48de51340a09020b7e9d9479e1e81ff766191.webp'
/home/exl/—1—ARCHIVE—1—/—3—previews—3—/734a8a0bac3a83e0f6c69416a26ec5cd211a6d742f3df63bb72bdbe6431b57c30677bc11551ba4aaaecac15ed2c48de51340a09020b7e9d9479e1e81ff766191.webp: Invalid argument
```

As suggested here ([FFMPEG command runs in terminal but not by subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569389/ffmpeg-command-runs-in-terminal-but-not-by-subprocess)) i tried using `which` determine path to correct version, but this command returns `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` both in python and in terminal.

`which ffmpeg` (both `subprocess.run(['which', 'ffmpeg'], capture_output=True).stdout` and terminal): `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`

`ffmpeg -version`: **5.1.1-1ubuntu1**

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.1-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-1ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-shared
```

`subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-version'], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()`: **5.0.1**

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.1.0 (GCC)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --disable-everything --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-vulkan --enable-zlib --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libxcb --enable-vdpau --enable-vaapi --enable-encoder='ac3,alac,flac,libfdk_aac,g723_1,mp2,libmp3lame,libopus,libspeex,pcm_alaw,pcm_mulaw,pcm_f32le,pcm_s16be,pcm_s24be,pcm_s16le,pcm_s24le,pcm_s32le,pcm_u8,tta,libvorbis,wavpack,' --enable-encoder='ass,ffv1,libaom_av1,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,mjpeg_vaapi,rawvideo,theora,vp8_vaapi,libopenh264' --enable-decoder='adpcm_g722,alac,flac,g723_1,g729,libfdk_aac,libopus,libspeex,mp2,mp3,m4a,pcm_alaw,pcm_mulaw,pcm_f16le,pcm_f24le,pcm_f32be,pcm_f32le,pcm_f64be,pcm_f64le,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16be_planar,pcm_s24be,pcm_s16le,pcm_s16le_planar,pcm_s24le,pcm_s24le_planar,pcm_s32le,pcm_s32le_planar,pcm_s64be,pcm_s64le,pcm_s8,pcm_s8_planar,pcm_u8,pcm_u24be,pcm_u24le,pcm_u32be,pcm_u32le,tta,vorbis,wavpack,' --enable-decoder='ass,ffv1,mjpeg,mjpegb,libaom_av1,libdav1d,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,rawvideo,theora,vp8,vp9,libopenh264' --enable-encoder='bmp,gif,jpegls,png,tiff,webp,' --enable-decoder='bmp,gif,jpegls,png,tiff,webp,' --enable-hwaccel='vp8_vaapi,mjpeg_vaapi,' --enable-parser='aac,ac3,flac,mjpeg,mpegaudio,mpeg4video,opus,vp3,vp8,vp9,vorbis,' --enable-muxer='ac3,ass,flac,g722,gif,matroska,mp3,mpegvideo,rtp,ogg,opus,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16le,wav,webm,' --enable-demuxer='aac,ac3,ass,flac,g722,gif,image_jpeg_pipe,image_png_pipe,image_webp_pipe,matroska,mjpeg,mov,mp3,mpegvideo,ogg,pcm_mulaw,pcm_alaw,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16le,rtp,wav,' --enable-filter='crop,scale,overlay,amix,amerge,aresample,format,aformat,fps,transpose,pad,' --enable-indev='v4l2,xcbgrab,' --enable-protocol='crypto,file,pipe,rtp,srtp,rtsp,tcp,udp,unix,' --arch=x86_64 --enable-libopenh264
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regardless of "which"'s output it seems you have to find the 5.1.1 ffmpeg and use its full path in the subprocess call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Run code outside PyCharm

I used PyCharm (Flatpak) to run python script, when i tried to run my script from terminal (`python3 main.py`) everything worked fine.

I think PyCharm uses `ffmpeg` from Flatpak.

`sudo find -P -name 'ffmpeg'`:

```
./usr/bin/ffmpeg
./usr/share/doc/ffmpeg
./usr/share/lintian/overrides/ffmpeg
./usr/share/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/22.08/98f43f6aeceb6f391e12513ea6f602744ada862fc58daf9691a648cc215b719f/files/bin/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/22.08/98f43f6aeceb6f391e12513ea6f602744ada862fc58daf9691a648cc215b719f/files/share/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/43/1e077cd7e0c8f9cc0ec2070f1b71f61f44327e437b128eaa9cde6abd1c866091/files/bin/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/43/1e077cd7e0c8f9cc0ec2070f1b71f61f44327e437b128eaa9cde6abd1c866091/files/share/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08/253961492abde2982b4c8b9b1e7d45acd72e08e8c84ee7bdc45b491e966072ca/files/bin/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08/253961492abde2982b4c8b9b1e7d45acd72e08e8c84ee7bdc45b491e966072ca/files/share/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08/c7252386179c4c1ecf5d93bdaec6ca82852dddfdae7112b5c3177f7424c4a928/files/bin/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08/c7252386179c4c1ecf5d93bdaec6ca82852dddfdae7112b5c3177f7424c4a928/files/share/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/app/org.blender.Blender/x86_64/stable/99b3ea83388bdcfba5d2cb41ab22057809aa1259a1345c0fc0c789e9ea94669e/files/lib/ffmpeg
./var/lib/flatpak/app/org.blender.Blender/x86_64/stable/99b3ea83388bdcfba5d2cb41ab22057809aa1259a1345c0fc0c789e9ea94669e/files/blender/3.3/scripts/presets/ffmpeg
```

`/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/22.08/98f43f6aeceb6f391e12513ea6f602744ada862fc58daf9691a648cc215b719f/files/bin/ffmpeg -version`: **5.0.1**